# Using Python subprocess.call to call bash script and agruments unsucessfully

Tags: linux, bash, python-3.x

I'm working on a project for managing blocks of IP addresses in a lab environment where we have a limited number of address available.  For example users are allowed to create virtual machines in the lab as needed but should assign an IP of say an available range of 50.

The program will empower users to choose available IP's by pinging the range sequentially and giving output of what IP address respond.

I'm stuck trying to find a way for ping to respond with a 1 or 0.  I might be going about it all wrong.  I've written a bash shell script which run fine on its own to return 1 or 0.  I'm now attempting to use call from the subprocess module in python to call the script but i never get to the second argument.  In addition the second arg when converted to a string give me syntax errors.

```
###Shell script###

#!/bin/bash

if ping -c 1 $1 >/dev/null; then
echo "1"
else
echo "0"
fi

###Python code calling ./ping.sh###
import subprocess
host = str(input('Host Please:   '))
output = subprocess.call(['./ping.sh', host], shell=True)

###Output of python code###

jon@WartHead ~/Desktop/Python/Python-3.3.0 $ python ip.py 
Host Please:   127.0.0.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ip.py", line 2, in <module>
    host = str(input('Host Please:   '))
  File "<string>", line 1
    127.0.0.1
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is one of my first python scripts written, any help is much welcomed.

Jon

Comment: You're running the script in the system Python 2. I assume you have a local build of Python 3.3, but you didn't run it with `./python ip.py`. Also, calling `str` on the result of `input` is unnecessary. It returns a string.

Comment: You're passing the argument to the shell that runs `ping.sh`. For example, try this `subprocess.call(['./ping.sh $0', host], shell=True)`. With `shell=True`, you generally want args to be a string. Otherwise use the default `shell=False`.

Comment: Thanks eryksun, $0 fixed my syntax and for the input comment!  Working as expected now.

Comment: Using `$0` was just to highlight why you should either use a string for `args` or use `shell=False`. Rarely would anyone want to use `shell=True` with an `args` list.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this;

```
import re,commands


class CheckAlive:
    def __init__(self,firstIP,lastIP):
        for checkIP in range(firstIP,lastIP):
            myCommand = commands.getstatusoutput('ping -c ' + '127.0.0.' + str(checkIP))
            searchString = r'ping: unknown host'

            match = re.search(searchString,str(myCommand))

            if match:
                # these hosts are not alive
                print '127.0.0.' + str(checkIP) + " host is not up."
            else:
                # these hosts are alive
                print '127.0.0.' + str(checkIP) + " host is up."

CheckAlive(0,254) # checks all hosts from 127.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.254
```

Comment: A much more direct approach to my end goal, thank you very much.

Comment: The `commands` module is deprecated in 2.6+ and removed from Python 3. Use `subprocess`.